# why is my service variable null?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When ever I run the below script for some reason the $Service is null?

I know the service exists but nothing appears in the variable section in PowerGUI Script Editor. This is messing up with the IF-ELSE statement in the script where if the service is started it displays "STARTED" to the end user.

Is it the space in the name of the service? If I just executed the service variable on its own then it displays the full contents of the service so it is not like it cannot find the service..

Here is a picture of the NULL variables being null:

[image]

SCRIPT:

```
clear
#$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"

Import-Module PSRemoteRegistry

$Logfile = "C:\temp\netbackup_version.log"

Function LogWrite
{
    param([string]$logstring)

    Add-Content $Logfile -Value $logstring
}

$computer = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\netbackup_servers1.txt

foreach ($computer1 in $computer){

        $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computer1)
        $RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Veritas\\NetBackup\\CurrentVersion")
        $NetbackupVersion1 = $RegKey.GetValue("PackageVersion")

    if (test-connection $computer1 -quiet) 
    {

    $Service = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'NetBackup Client Service'" -ComputerName $computer1

            if($Service.state -eq 'Running')
            {
                LogWrite "$computer1 STARTED $NetbackupVersion1"

            }
            else
            {
                LogWrite "$computer1 STOPPED $NetbackupVersion1"
            }
    }
    else 
    {
        LogWrite "$computer1 is down" -foregroundcolor RED
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can run `Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'NetBackup Client Service'" -ComputerName $computer1` (with one of the computernames) manually? The variable is $null when no match was found. I'm suggesting it just to verify that remoting is working. Also, are you sure that "NetBackup Client Service" is `Name` and not `DisplayName`?

Comment: BINGO! Darn Netbackup.......you gave me an idea to check the display name against older versions of the client and it is called something else! I thought they were all the same name across the board...guess I have to re-adjust my naming of the services now...thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't expect older versions of a service to have the same Service Name as a new updated version! The older servers that have old Netbackup clients have a different name to the new ones - that is why the script was not displaying the names! Thanks for Graimer to double checking this!